# My paper is unpublished, not novel and contains a mistake. How to list it in a CV?

Tags: publications, cv, arxiv

For my master thesis, I worked on a topic that was new both for me, and my supervising professor. Because of that, we missed a well-known paper of our field, and I basically rediscovered the same idea.

We tried to publish it in two conferences, but it was rejected both times (unfortunately, no one pointed out that the work already existed, it was rejected because of too low impact according to the referees). Currently, it is published on arXiv. We are working on an updated version that includes a reference to the existing paper, and highlights that our results were discovered independently but are not novel.

To make matters worse, I also made a mistake in the central proof, so while the idea is correct, the conclusion needs to be weakened (that was done correctly in the original work).

Now, I am a Ph.D. student working for the same advisor. The paper has not been cited so far, but we will need to refer to it soon in a public report about a software we wrote, based on our technique. Also, my advisor is not in favor of taking down the paper entirely.

I felt bad about this for a while, but have come to terms with it now. While it is a bit embarrassing, I guess mistakes happen and there was no malintent. I am making up for it by doing an extensive literature review now, to avoid making the same mistake twice.

My question is about how to refer to this paper in my CV (or when presenting myself in general). I do have several other papers already, some of them in high-impact conferences with many citations (in a different sub-field). Currently, I have a section of my CV dedicated to those papers.
I'm not sure excluding the questionable paper is a good idea, because I don't want to make the impression that I'm trying to hide it. But I also want to make clear that I'm aware of the flaws, in a way that doesn't harm my overall appearance.

The general format of my list of publications is as follows:

```
[Paper title], [authors], [conference name], [acceptance rate], [number of citations]
 - Main contribution
 - Second contribution
```

I'm thinking about using something like this:

```
[Questionable paper title], [authors], non-peer reviewed (arXiv)
 - Independently discovered [known technique]
```

This would not hide the fact that it's known, but also doesn't put too much focus on the paper. Also, it doesn't stress the fact that it contains a mistake (that would be part of the updated arXiv version). Is this reasonable?

The question also extends to how to present myself to other researchers, when they ask me about prior publications in a less formal setting. My plan was to own up to it, and reply something along the lines of "For my master thesis I focused on improving [topic]. Unfortunately, I missed [known paper] and independently discovered the same results." (again, not focusing on the mistake I made).

Comment: Do you have an "expository papers" section in your CV? If yes, you can add it there -- while not quite expository, it is (once corrected and put into context) a similar beast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are still working on it and haven't abandoned it, it seems an obvious candidate for a "Work in Progress" section of your CV. Other current projects can be listed there also.

You don't really need to apologize, especially in the CV.

Comment: How would you describe the content of the paper? Still as "Independently discovered X", or differently? Or only give the title of the paper?
To clarify: The updated version will include the reference to the known paper, and a note that the results are too strong. I'm not sure we will actually redo the experiments, as that would be a lot of work and is probably not worth it. Future work will focus on actually novel ideas, and be published as its own paper.

Comment: And maybe as a follow up question: The paper will never be published at any conference, given that there's no new information in it. Once the paper is updated, should I move it back to the main list of papers, or drop it completely? It's not peer-reviewed, after all

Comment: @MissedKnownResult Maybe it's different in your field, but in mine a CV is just a list of papers, not annotated.

Comment: Is a description even necessary? If you need to say something, describe the project, not the paper. If you get enough results to replace it, or if you otherwise drop the project then either drop it from the CV or describe it as "replaced by ..." as appropriate.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm in CS. I think giving just a list of papers is the norm there, too. I included short descriptions to give a very quick overview (and to stress the impact, given that I was applying to research roles as a master student, when usually a last-year Ph.D (or similar) was expected. Maybe now is a good time to go back to just using a list. It will also help to save some space.

Comment: Agree with @BryanKrause (as is often the case) that descriptions aren't needed in most situations. But, in an interview, it is fine to admit that an old project failed and was abandoned. That is the nature of research. And, for the time-limited research done for most MS degrees it isn't especially uncommon.

Comment: @MissedKnownResult If you're applying for positions that expect a degree you don't have then it's highly unlikely that formatting a CV differently than the norm will make up the gap.

Comment: @BryanKrause and Buffy, Thanks for the great feedback! I'll wait a bit before accepting the answer, but you gave me good advice. BryanKrause, maybe it worked despite and not because of the unusual formatting, but I did end up getting the internship I was applying for. Of cause, n=1 is no good basis to extrapolate for general advice.

Comment: It is always good to wait a bit before accepting. Note that you can also withdraw and assign an acceptance to another answer. See the help center for more: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2):

There is also always the possibility of just not listing it at all. Your CV is meant to highlight the positives of your career. We don't list the rejected papers and proposals and other failures :-)

Comment: I agree with this (a lot). But the problem is that the paper is on arXiv already. I don't use that, but, IIRC, you can't withdraw a paper there. So, not listing is, which is fine, also requires you can have something to say about it if asked.

Comment: @buffy You can always replace it by a newer version that states that the original paper has been withdrawn. That said, I don't think anyone is really going to go out and do a literature search on a candidate when they have the full list of publications right in front of them!